# unable to see graph in grafana for custom metric cloud watch

Tags: ubuntu, grafana

I created custom metric in cloud watch for memory and disk usages, the graph is reflecting in cloud watch metric, the same cloudwatch I used as my data source in grafana for reflecting graph or data points, it does not reflect for memory usages and disk usages i.e for custom metric however it reflects for default metrics of cloudwatch like CPU utilization, etc. I am using grafana version 6.3 and ubuntu as os. Help me out for the same

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the `custom metric namespace` in your cloudwatch config in Grafana? An example of setting this option can be found [here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/4445#issuecomment-199842645). If you've set this correctly, it might be that you need to enable `points` in the graph drawing options as demonstrated [here](https://community.grafana.com/t/need-help-with-cloudwatch-custom-metrics/844/2).

Comment: followed the process as mentioned above still issue is not resolved, a custom metric namespace is not showing on the screen and no data points are reflecting

Comment: followed the above-mentioned process still, the issue is not resolved